# Python vars() global name error

Tags: python, global

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding what's going wrong with the following function:

```
def ness():
 pie='yum'
 vars()[pie]=4
 print vars()[pie]
 print yum
```

So When I run that I get this result:

```
>>> ness()
4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in ness
NameError: global name 'yum' is not defined
```

If I don't write it as a function and just type it in on the command line one line at a time it works fine, like so:

```
>>> pie='yum'
>>> vars()[pie]=4
>>> print vars()[pie]
4
>>> print yum
4
>>>
```

Edit:
Suppose I wanted to make things a bit more complicated than this and instead of setting yum to a value and printing that value, I define some functions, and want to call one of them based on some input:

```
def ness(choo):
    dic={}
    dessert=()
    dnum=[10,100]
    desserts='pie'
    dic[dessert]=str(desserts[bisect(dnum,choo)])
    vars()[dic[dessert]]()
def p():
    print 'ummmm ummm'
def i():
    print 'hooo aaaaa'
def e():
    print 'woooo'
```

So when I call ness I get a key error:

```
>>> ness(3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in ness
KeyError: 'p'
```

Now I know I can do things like this with some elif statements, but I'm wondering if this would work too, and if using bisect  like this would be more efficient (say if i need to check 1000 values of choo) than using elifs.

Thanks much for the assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is way to do it with exec

```
>>> def ness():
...  pie='yum'
...  exec pie+"=4"
...  print vars()[pie]
...  print yum
...
>>>
>>> ness()
4
4
```

But Instead of doing that, using a new dict is better and safe

```
>>> def ness():
...  dic={}
...  pie='yum'
...  dic[pie]=4
...  print dic[pie]
...  print dic['yum']
...
>>> ness()
4
4
>>>
```

Comment: Using exec did the trick for the more complicated example I wrote above (no key errors like trying to use dict along with vars. What exactly makes using dict safer than exec? Is it what gnibbler said below:
"The returned dictionary should not be modified: the effects on the corresponding symbol table are undefined"

Doe this mean using exec in this manner can cause unforeseeable issues?

Comment: exec can execute any python codes, for eg, `exec "os.system('reboot_your_pc')", so its the best to avoid using it.

Comment: Also exec can give you a confusing stacktrace and will be much slower than an explicit dictionary (it has to be parsed every time from scratch).

Answer (score 4):

`vars()` within a function gives you the local namespace, just like `locals()` -- see [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=vars#vars).  Outside of a function (e.g. at the prompt) `locals()` (and `vars()` of course) gives you the module's global namespace, just like `globals()`.  As [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=vars#locals) say, trying to assign to a function's local variable through `locals()` (or equivalently, `vars()` inside a function) is not supported in Python.  If you want to assign to a *global* variable, as you do when you're at the prompt (or otherwise outside of a function), use `globals()` instead of `vars()` (maybe not the cleanest approach -- global variables are understandably frowned upon -- but it does work).

Answer (score 1):

It's [not safe](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#vars) to modify the dict returned by vars()

> vars([object])¶
>
> Without an argument, act like locals().
>
> With a module, class or class instance object as argument (or
>   anything else that has a **dict**
>   attribute), return that attribute.
>
> Note
>
> The returned dictionary should not be modified: the effects on the
>   corresponding symbol table are
>   undefined.

Your second example is a special case. `vars()` is equivalent to `globals()` in the global namespace, and the dict returned by `globals()` behaves as you would expect ( but is frowned upon )

```
>>> id(vars()),id(globals())
(3085426868L, 3085426868L)
```

Answer (score 0):

`vars()` is equivalent to `locals()`, which in the case of the function is the local variables in its scope and at in the interactive interpreter at the scope you have it, `vars() is globals()`. `locals()` is for reading only; the effects of trying to change it are undefined (and in practice, just doesn't work). `globals()` *can* be modified, but you **still** should never directly put anything in the dict it returns.

Answer (score 0):

[Edit: I must be wrong here, since the 'exec' example works.]

As everyone points out, it's a bad idea to modify vars().  You can understand the error, though, by realizing that python in some sense doesn't "see" that "yum" is a local.  "print yum" is still resolved as a global reference; this happens before any code is executed.

It's the same reason you get an UnboundLocalError from:

```
>>> y = 100
>>> def foo(x):
...   if x == 1:
...     y = 10
...   print y
... 
>>> foo(1)
10
>>> foo(2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in foo
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'y' referenced before assignment
```